# kubernetes - environment variables not works with integers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, yaml, appsettings

I have one .netcore Web App running in "docker". So started to cluster it with kubernetes. Has four configs on the appsettings.json that will be converted by environment variables(all between "${}"):

```
   {
  "ConnectionSettings": [
    {
      "id": "${connectionSettings.connectionString.idMongoDb}",
      "databaseName": "${connectionSettings.connectionString.databaseName}",
      "connectionString": "${connectionSettings.connectionString.mongoDB}"
    }
  ],
    {
      "Key": "Token.Issuer",
      "Value": "${configuration.token.issuer}",
      "Description": "",
      "ModifiedDate": "2018-05-05 00:00:00.0000000",
      "ModifiedBy": "system",
      "AllowedProfiles": 1
    }
}
```

It's a bit of my **.yaml** file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-dev-api-dep
  labels:
    app: myapp-dev-api-dep
    tier: app
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp-dev-api
      tier: app
      version: v1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp-dev-api
        tier: app
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapp-dev-api
          image: 'myappapi_tstkube:latest'
          env:
            - name: connectionSettings.connectionString.mongoDB
              value: mongodb://192.168.20.99:27017
            - name: configuration.token.issuer
              value: '86400'
          ports:
            - name: http 
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 3600
            httpGet:
              path: /swagger/index.html
              port: 80
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 25m
              memory: 200Mi
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
```

Take a look in my configs:

[image]

The variable "**connectionSettings.connectionString.mongoDB**" works. But the variable "**configuration.token.issuer**" can't substituted on the appsetting.

Made some tests. I found the problem only with variables of numbers.

Has somebody an idea or have you had the problem?

vlw

Comment: Have you tried setting the environment variable `configuration.token.issuer` using double quotes as a string like `"86400"`?

Comment: yes. One and two quotes("86400", '86400').

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was in the yamls identification code. You may have many problems with the error space in the yaml file.

https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques.md

About the number. Both answers are right. You can use single quotation marks '86400' and ACII "\ x38 \ x36 \ x34 \ x30 \ x30".

Thank you everybody

Answer (score 3):

You have to use ASCII codes for numbers. So your deployment spec will look like

```
env:
  - name: connectionSettings.connectionString.mongoDB
    value: "mongodb://192.168.20.99:27017"
  - name: configuration.token.issuer
    value: "\x38\x36\x34\x30\x30"
```

And check env variables:

```
sukhoversha@sukhoversha:~/GCP$ kubectl  exec myapp-dev-api-dep-7948866b56-6cnmk  env | grep con
connectionSettings.connectionString.mongoDB=mongodb://192.168.20.99:27017
configuration.token.issuer=86400
```